# RabbitMQ hanged up

Tags: centos, rabbitmq

I have single RabbitMQ 3.6.1-1 installed on CentOS 7.2.1511, with Erlang R16B-03.16.el7.
Today I cleaned it up:

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl force_reset
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

It worked for some time and now (maybe, after 8 hours of data processing) it doesn't respond to application requests and status check:

```
# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node 'rabbit@RabbitMQ-Server' ...
^C
Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
```

Also, I have a lot of messages in `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log`. These messages are repeating in infinite loop:
http://pastebin.com/38AXyw4n

There are nothing in other logs:

```
# ls -lS
total 6481664
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     2365375398 Apr 30 21:34 startup_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq          0 Apr 30 14:18 rabbit@RabbitMQ-Server-sasl.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq          0 Apr 30 20:45 rabbit@RabbitMQ-Server.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              0 Apr 30 14:18 startup_err
```

What's wrong with RabbitMQ? How I could restore it back to working state?

Comment: It's what it says "Error in log handler". You have the stack trace, the last function it tried to execute is `error_logger_file_h:write_event` but it fails. Error `function_clause` means the code exited because the function either doesn't exist (e.g. the module isn't loaded or the function is no longer there) or it doesn't accept the arguments with which the code tries to call it. And then you have the arguments. I would propose that you try to follow the stack trace (you have modules, functions and lines on the stack) and check what's wrong with the arguments or the last function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was some inconstistency between versions of RabbitMQ and Erlang. I've installed Erlang package from [RabbitMQ maintainers](https://rabbitmq.com/releases/erlang/), after that logging and AMQP handshakes began working as expected.

```
systemctl stop rabbitmq-server
killall epmd

yum remove rabbitmq-server
yum remove erlang
yum autoremove

wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/erlang/erlang-18.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.1/rabbitmq-server-3.6.1-1.noarch.rpm
yum install erlang-18.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
yum install rabbitmq-server-3.6.1-1.noarch.rpm
```